# How to loose the image 'alt' attribute in my custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I've created a custom post type but now I cannot seem to figure out how to loose the image name (under the image) once a project is opened. When a project is clicked all I need it to show except for the image would be the projects name and the tweet link. [Link](http://www.must.ee/uusmust/ad/#portfolio) to the test site.

In my functions.php I have:

```
<?php

require_once('portfolio-type.php');
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');

function my_excerpt_length($length) {
return 25; 
}

add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');  
function new_excerpt_more($text){  

return ' ';  
}  

function portfolio_thumbnail_url($pid){
$image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($pid);  
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'screen-shot');  
return  $image_url[0];  
}
?>
```

In portfolio-type.php:

```
 <?php

 if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 270, 170, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
add_image_size( 'screen-shot', 720, 540 ); // Full size screen
 }

 add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');  

 function portfolio_register() {  
 $args = array(  
    'label' => __('Portfolio'),  
    'singular_label' => __('Project'),  
    'public' => true,  
    'show_ui' => true,  
    'capability_type' => 'post',  
    'hierarchical' => false,  
    'rewrite' => true,  
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')  
   );  

register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );  
 }  

register_taxonomy("project-type", array("portfolio"), array("hierarchical"  =>  true, "label" => "Project Types", "singular_label" => "Project Type",   "rewrite" => true));
 ?>
```

And finally in my index.php I have:

```
<div id="posts" class="row isotope">

                      <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>  

                          <?php  
                              $title= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_title()));  
                              $desc= str_ireplace('"', '', trim(get_the_content()));  
                          ?>     

                          <div class="item post item span4 isotope-item">

                            <a class="project-wrp fancybox" title="<?=$title?>" rel="lightbox[work]" href="<?php print portfolio_thumbnail_url($post->ID) ?>"><div class="profile-photo"><div class="profile-icon">&#0102;</div><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>  
                            <div class="project-name"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
                            <div class="project-client"><?php echo $desc; ?></div>
                            </a>
                          </div>  
                      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>  


</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "loose the image url"?

Comment: When you click the project you'll see the image name right under the projects name. I'll change my question because calling it 'url' seems misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That description-like element between the image name and the "Tweet" link looks like it is being pulled from the image `alt` attribute. I don't see the code that actually produces that section-- I can't find "Tweet" in what you posted. However, you *might* be able to get rid of that by passing an empty alt attribute like so:

```
the_post_thumbnail(array('230','170'),array('alt' => ''));
```

Comment: Adding `'thumbnail',array('alt' => '')` to the `the_post_thumbnail()` in index.php made the image `alt` attribute disappear but for some reason the thumbnail images are now extremely foggy.

Comment: The thumbnails are loading. Were you loading a different size before? Undo that and look at the source. What size image is actually loading?

Comment: I undid it and the image size is 230px x 170px. With the `'thumbnail',array('alt' => '')` the image size is 150px x 150px.

Comment: Without a parameter that should default to the post thumbnail size. I don't know why it isn't, but you can pass those parameters too. Give me a second. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: The code is missing an `'` in `('230',170')`. After changing that the images are okay and the `alt` attribute values are not showing. Many thanks [s_ha_dum](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21376/s-ha-dum).

Comment: If this solved the question please mark it as "Accepted". Look for the check mark on the left.